# How to fix error "Only one usage of each socket address is normally permitted"

Tags: c#, vb.net, tcp

I have 1 process that acts as a server (TcpListener) and one or more processes that act as clients (TcpClient). The clients are sending Tcp requests to the server every 1-2 seconds to which the server responds with a result message.

In normal conditions the server will use TcpListener.Stop when it closes, but sometimes the server will crash (for whatever reason) and then this is not done. If I then try to restart then I get the following error:

"Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted"

I *only* get this error when there are clients running who keep trying to connect despite the TcpListener is not there anymore (crashed).

I *don't* get this error when I first manually close/kill all clients before restarting the server/TcpListener.

I'm looking for an automatic recovery procedure that deals with this error/problem. How can this be done?

Below you'll find code examples of the server and the client.

BTW: Although the codes examples are in VB.NET, I can also handle C# code. That's why I tagged this question with both VB and C#.

Code example for server/TcpListener:

```
Public Shared Sub Thread_TcpListener_GUI()

    While True

        Dim tcpClient As TcpClient = Nothing
        Dim tcpListener As TcpListener = Nothing

        Try

            tcpListener = New TcpListener(System.Net.IPAddress.Any, 4960)
            tcpListener.ExclusiveAddressUse = False
            Call tcpListener.Start()

            While True

                tcpClient = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient

                Dim tcpNetworkStream As NetworkStream = tcpClient.GetStream()

                Dim strMessageReceived As String = ""

                'Get received message
                While tcpNetworkStream.DataAvailable
                    Dim byteReceived(tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize) As Byte
                    tcpNetworkStream.Read(byteReceived, 0, CInt(tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize))
                    strMessageReceived &= Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteReceived).Trim(Convert.ToChar(0))
                End While

                'Send response message
                If strMessageReceived <> "" Then
                    Dim strResponse As String = "Received!"
                    Dim byteResponse As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strResponse)
                    tcpNetworkStream.Write(byteResponse, 0, byteResponse.Length)
                End If

            End While

        Catch ex As Exception
            Call Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)

        Finally

            Try
                If tcpClient IsNot Nothing Then
                    If tcpClient.Connected Then
                        tcpClient.Close()
                    End If
                End If
            Catch ex As Exception
            End Try

            Try
                If tcpListener IsNot Nothing Then
                    tcpListener.Stop()
                    tcpListener = Nothing
                End If
            Catch ex As Exception
            End Try

            Thread.Sleep(1500)

        End Try

    End While

End Sub
```

Code example client:

```
Public Shared Sub TcpClient_SendMessage(ByVal strMessage As String)

    Dim tcpClient As System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient = Nothing
    Dim strResponse As String = ""

    While True

        Try

            tcpClient = New System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient()
            tcpClient.ExclusiveAddressUse = False

            tcpClient.Connect("localhost", 4960)

            Dim tcpNetworkStream As NetworkStream = tcpClient.GetStream()

            'Send message
            Dim byteMessage As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strMessage)
            tcpNetworkStream.Write(byteMessage, 0, byteMessage.Length)

            'Get respronse message
            strResponse = ""
            While tcpNetworkStream.DataAvailable
                Dim byteResponse(tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize) As Byte
                tcpNetworkStream.Read(byteResponse, 0, CInt(tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize))
                strResponse &= Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteResponse).Trim(Convert.ToChar(0))
            End While

            'Do something with response here ....

        Catch ex As Exception

            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)

        Finally

            Try
                If tcpClient IsNot Nothing Then
                    If tcpClient.Connected Then
                        tcpClient.Close()
                        tcpClient = Nothing
                    End If
                End If
            Catch ex As Exception
            End Try

        End Try

    End While

End Sub
```

Comment: At the client code, have you tried using a Socket and NetworkStream directly? I seem to recall getting something similar, and that fixed it...

Comment: @Marc: No. Can you give me an example?

Answer (score -1):

A thread is either a background thread or a foreground thread. Background threads are identical to foreground threads, except that background threads do not prevent a process from terminating. Once all foreground threads belonging to a process have terminated, the common language runtime ends the process. Any remaining background threads are stopped and do not complete.

The problem here is that the listener keeps on running even if the app is crashed. This is because it is running on a foreground thread. So, you need to make it a background thread, so that it stops with the application.

```
    Dim receiverThread As Thread

    receiverThread = New Thread(AddressOf Thread_TcpListener_GUI)
    receiverThread.IsBackground = True
    receiverThread.Start()
```

Try starting your thread this way. Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but unfortunately it doesn't solve it.

Comment: try using this modified answer.

Comment: I know that it's not possible to have more than 1 listener for the same port and that's also not what I'm doing or trying to do. There's only one process that's listening to port 4960, as in the code example of the server. Imho the problem here is that when the server is crashing without releasing/closing the listener it's kept open and therefore cannot be reestablished. Somehow I need to be able to dispose the listener or tell the client to stop communicating with the "crashed" listener.

Comment: The finally will execute whether the app crashes or not. Can you tell us where exactly is your app crashing?

Comment: With crash I mean suddenly end of the application process. That could f.e. be ending it manually via Windows Taskmanager or a memory leak. In that case Finally will never be executed.

Comment: Can you please provide the code where you are starting the thread. The thread which calls Thread_TcpListener_GUI()

Comment: Please check my changed answer. Hope this solves your problem.